# Executing statement after 10 seconds

Tags: java, timer

I am running my java listener codes.

What happens is that my server will send some command to the client.

Thereafter I want to wait and see in 10s if there is no reply, then keep retrying for 5 times.

Below is what I do.

```
//Select code from the db with the codeID, codeText.
//send the code to the client.
long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = t+10000;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {

}
//Select from db to check if codeupdated.
```

If updated dont do anything else I need to repeat the above pause ?

I having issue to repeat it for 5 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee for your construct to last exactly 10 seconds, and it's very costly in terms of performance.

Just use `Thread.sleep`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // TODO your request here
        boolean success = true; // TODO change to whatever outcome of your
                                // request
        if (success) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000l);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // TODO handle interruptions if applicable
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to repeat the it for 5 times then if it failed ?

Comment: I think after I send I must run once the Thread.sleep(10001) then only get into this loop am I right? Cause else this will run immediately after I send my code.

Comment: Yes, the `Thread.sleep(1000l)` (notice the "l" for `long`, not a "1") will take place after your first request in this snippet. If you want to sleep first, request later just play with the statements a bit and invert them.

Comment: What is 'l' long  for ? Yes after my first request I want to sleep and then only call this loop if it failed. I guess that is fine right. So with that I dont need to change you loop. Another thing you mention its costly for performance any reason for it?

Comment: @user2711681 looping like you did in your example is, because you are looping x number of times and initializing a long object every iteration. In the snippet I added it isn't. Here's a link to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for primitive data types, you'll find more about `long`s.

Comment: @Is 10000 a long number I dont think so right is still within the normal int range isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Thread.sleep(10*1000); //sleep 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Thread.sleep()` to pause execution

It's well explained here : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: after the sleep how to repeatly check it has pass or not? IF pass then update it status and move to the next code? Else repeat it for 5 times ?